# The Mathematics of Hexagonal Grids in SVG

Tags: geometry

This is my first time posting on this forum, but my mathematics skills are a little weak when push comes to shove.

Here is my question:

> What is a formula that maps the center-points of horizontal hexes in a cubic grid system to a specific point in an SVG plane.
>   *in SVG space Y is inverted: negative Y goes up on the screen, positive Y goes down (don't ask why it just does)

Some context:

I have JavaScript implementation drawing the hex the way I want from any given center-point. This means I just need the formula to output the X coordinate and the Y coordinate

This should be possible because each X, Y, Z label is unique within any given grid whose center-point should map to a specific X, Y coordinate in 2d space.

I spent several hours thinking about this and couldn't wrap my head around how to go about describing it mathematically, so an explanation of why it works would be welcome as I'm always up for learning new things.

**

Inputs: (X, Y, Z) cubic coordinate

> Always an integer

Outputs: (X, Y) SVG coordinate

> Float or Integer *that is the center-point of the hex

EDIT: clarification

**I'm not mapping 3d space to 2d space. A cubic hex grid looks like the following [image: An Example of a Horizontal Cubic Hex Grid]

It's also worth mentioning that the formula will be dependent on the size of the hex. Which for the purposes of my program is measured as the length of a straight line between itself and any of its neighbors since all hexes are the same size?

Comment: Let $\ell$ be the distance between center of nearby hexagon, try
$(X_{\rm svg}, Y_{\rm svg}) = \frac{\ell}{\sqrt{3}}\left( X - \frac{Y+Z}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(Z-Y)\right)$ and see whether it does what you want..